# Internet Explorer filters <input> transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I want to make an `<input type="text">` transparent under IE and this 
`filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)` makes the job 
however, the text can't be seen... is there some workaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about the following.

```
<input type="text" class="transparent"/>

<style>
input.transparent{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none; 
}
</style>
```

Also the IE version makes quite a difference.